# Using regex with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having a little trouble trying to use regex with beautiful soup.

My html as follows:

```html
[<strong>See the full calendar</strong>, <strong>See all events</strong>, <strong>See all committee meetings</strong>, <strong>526 spaces</strong>, <strong>89 spaces</strong>, <strong>53 spaces</strong>, <strong>154 spaces</strong>, <strong>194 spaces</strong>, <strong>See all news releases</strong>]
[<strong>See the full calendar</strong>, <strong>See all events</strong>, <strong>See all committee meetings</strong>, <strong>526 spaces</strong>, <strong>89 spaces</strong>, <strong>53 spaces</strong>, <strong>154 spaces</strong>, <strong>194 spaces</strong>, <strong>See all news releases</strong>]
```

What I want is just the number of spaces in between the strong tags.

I have tried using:

```
print(soup.find_all(re.compile("\d\d\d\s[a-zA-Z]{6}|(strong)")))
```

However, this is returning everything that `print(soup.find_all('strong'))` does.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Thank you! Have tried `print(len(soup.find_all('strong').split())-1)` but got `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'split'` - any ideas? @Ludisposed

Comment: You want the sum of all spaces or each strong tag should have it's own space counter?

Comment: The end goal is to have this exported to csv, so each "x spaces" needs to be a separate record for each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use the `text` property of `soup.find_all`, and pass a compiled regex pattern:

```
import re
spaces = []
for tag in content.find_all(text=re.compile("\d+(?= spaces)")):
    spaces.append(int(tag.string.split()[0]))

print(spaces)
```

Output:

```
[526, 89, 53, 154, 194, 526, 89, 53, 154, 194]
```

Comment: Now I'm confused what OP wants, the number of spaces or the digit before the spaces in the strong tag. Using the text property is a nice feature I didn't know of

Comment: @Ludisposed Hence the "if I understood you correctly", haha. OP mentioned spaces, and there are a bunch of those tags with xxx spaces as content, so I assumed that's what they meant.

Comment: Yes after rereading: OP:"so each x spaces" I think you are right

Comment: Thanks both, yes this was what I was looking for! - Sorry if my post was confusing?!

Answer (score 1):

First find all strong tags

```
strong_tags = soup.find_all('strong')
spaces_in_tags = {}

# Afterwards iterate over the tags.. Then do either

for strong in strong_tags:
    # 1. (EDIT add \s+ so multiple spaces between words will count as 1 space)
    number_of_spaces = len(re.findall('\s+', strong))
    # 2.
    number_of_spaces2 = len(strong.split())-1

    # Then add them do a dictionary/list whatever suits your need
    # For example to have the string as the key parameter in a dictionary
    spaces_in_tags[strong] = number_of_spaces
```